# http headers for c# client to Java Service

Tags: c#, web-services, http, http-headers, http-authentication

Hi ive been trying to add http headers to a webclient in c# , ive been looking alot of places and have had little luck often people point to a Credentials class however i only have ClientCredentials my client also missing is a PreAuthenticate field?

The service is written in Java and I can add http headers to that as follows

```
reqHeaders.put(HEADER_NAME_USERNAME, Collections.singletonList(USER_NAME));
reqHeaders.put(HEADER_NAME_PASSWORD, Collections.singletonList(PASSWORD));
((BindingProvider) webWS).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,reqHeaders);
```

However i have no idea how to do this in c# ive tried endpoint address builder, ClientCredential, windows.ClientCredential basically anywehre i can find a username and passsword
When i make a request in java i capture the http packet in wireshark
looks kinds like this

```
+hypertext transfer protocol
+POST
  post stuff
 Password: mypass
 Username: username
 soapaction: ... and so on
```

i cant change the server side code all i know is if i can add two headers one called username and one password with values ill be Sheening (read:winning)

Comment: What are you using for your client? WCF, SoapHttpClientProtocol(aka asmx), rolling your own requests with HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: @CheeZe5 i access it by adding a service reference in a standard console application project I than create a new webservice object  ServiceReference1.WebsiteWSClient ws = nw .... and call requests of off that like ws.readCurrentData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx

This mostly answered my problem, instead of editing the app.config though i jsut added the newly defined behaviour class under

webservice.Endpoint.Behaviors.add(new CustomBehavior(params));